# react-native-sound audio file not playing in iOS 13

Tags: react-native, audio, ios13, playback, react-native-sound

I'm playing sound using `react-native-sound` and is playing on iOS 12 device but when I check in iOS 13 device is not playing.

here is my code

```
this.soundPlayer = new Sound(require('../assets/fly.mp3'), '', (error) => {
      console.log(error)
      if (error) {
        console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
        return;
      }
      this.soundPlayer.play()
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

if you load sound using `require` then use

```
this.soundPlayer = new Sound(require('../assets/fly.mp3'), (error) => {
      console.log(error)
      if (error) {
        console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
        return;
      }
      this.soundPlayer.play()
    })
```

and when you load sound in the network then use

```
this.soundPlayer = new Sound(require('../assets/fly.mp3'), '', (error) => {
      console.log(error)
      if (error) {
        console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
        return;
      }
      this.soundPlayer.play()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const notificationSound = new Sound('ring_tone.wav', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
        return;
    }
});
enter code here
```

**Please use following way in ios**
notificationSound.play(() => {});

**Android**
notificationSound.play();